# Using this.sendAction() in components?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I am using Ember 2.2.0

When writing components I used to propagate events from the component to the route (or whatever embeds the component) with `this.sendAction(…)`. I checked out the docs lately and discovered that they advise another approach.
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/

```
this.get('action')();
```

Since Ember is known to be very opinionated I want to stick as much to the best practices as possible. But I am not sure if the docs might be out of date or the tutorials using sendActions are.

So I would like what is the way to do this?

Comment: The decimal version is important--Ember 2.what?

Comment: Assume the latest version of the guides is as up to date as possible, the documentation team has taken a lot of care to make it so.

Comment: I read this article and helped me to clear a few things up [Ember send() and sendAction() – Developer Paradise – Medium](https://medium.com/developer-paradise/ember-send-and-sendaction-5e6ac9c80841)

Comment: `sendAction` has been deprecated in 3.4
https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_ember-component-send-action

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are using `this.sendAction('actionName')` you're bubbling up an action which you'll have to catch on the component/controller with `actions`

```
//controller/route/component.js
actions: {
  actionName: function() {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

If you want to send that up the chain, you'll have to call `sendAction('')` again on the component/controller and catch it again on the parent (and so on).

The other approach `this.get('action')()` uses closure actions, which are regular javascript functions. These are the preferred way to invoke actions in Ember 1.13.X as far as I know. One neat thing that closure actions have is that you can have return values. Meaning that you can have something like this:

```
//a controller
actions: {
  saveResult() {
    return this.get('model').save(); //notice the return (which returns a promise)
  }
}

//some template that uses the controller above
{{a-component save=(action 'saveResult')}} // Passes the saveResult action to the component

//a-component.js
actions: {
  someAction: function() {
     this.attrs.save().then(() => {
       //Do something with the return value
     });
  }
}
```

A lot can be written about closure actions, but others have written far better than I could, so I recommend the following articles:

- [Ember Closure Actions #1](http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-closure-actions-have-return-values)
- [Ember Closure Actions #2](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/29/ember-best-practice-stop-bubbling-and-use-closure-actions)
- [Ember Closure Actions #3](http://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-closure-actions/)

And if you're new to the whole DDAU (Data Down Actions Up) concept, I really recommend [Sam's article](https://medium.com/@sam.selikoff/lowest-common-ancestor-fbf5d5313a1) about the concept in general.

Update: There's also an addon (linked in the comments by @locks) which allows [closure actions to bubble to routes](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-route-action-helper). Note that if you look to upgrade Ember to more recent versions (3.8 and up), `route-action`s will not be compatible.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer! Will check out the articles. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. I also struggled to learn these concepts! Good luck with your ember help.

Comment: Thanks!Only downside is that i can't use {{my-component onSomething=(action 'theAction')}} when 'theAction' is defined within the route. So either I have to use a controller (will be deprecated as far as I know) or wrap everything in an additional component. At the moment I wanted to handle model specific actions (edit, create) at route level.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, sorry! Controllers will stay around at least until Ember 3.0. Work on routable compontents, which should deprecated controllers, is still being worked on as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For those using Ember version >=3.4:

> Use closure actions instead of `sendAction`

`sendAction` has been **deprecated in 3.4**. You can find an example of how to define  closure actions under the relevant deprecation text:

https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_ember-component-send-action